# git svn: password for svn is not stored

Tags: svn, git, authentication, https, git-svn

I'm using git against a central remote svn repository using 'git-svn'. The SVN repository uses https with a self-signed certificate. Everything works fine, with one nasty exception. As long as I use directly with  svn, the password is remembered, so it has to by typed only on the first command.

When using git-svn operations (e.g. dcommit, rebase), the password is no longer remembered and manual input is required. After a git-svn oparation, direct svn commands do no longer remember the password too, also prompting each time.

What's going on here? Any hints?

My environment: Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit, git-core and git-svn 1.7.0.4-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a similar usage scenario (svn over https, password, using git for a local repository and push/pull to the svn server), however I haven't encountered this issue you are mentioning.

One difference I see is that I set subversion to save my password and not to ask it every time. You could try that to see if it works.

And I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605519/does-git-svn-store-svn-passwords), it seems that wiping the whole ~/.subversion directory helped (make sure you have a backup of the directory if you try that)

Comment: Thanks for link to the other question. After deleting .subversion and reentering the password once it is remembered now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case git-svn asked for password every time since our infra dept set windows HOME environment variable to network disk recently.

My recommendation for diagnosing of this is to download [sysinternals procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and filter out everything but perl process and path containing "subversion" string. After that you can see what is happening