# where does git-svn save ssh credentials?

Tags: security, git, ssh, git-svn

I am using git-svn to develop code that is hosted on a SVN+SSH repository. I do not have to input my ssh password on the server every time I dcommit/update/rebase, so I assume it is cached somewhere.

Where are my credentials saved? Inside the .git directory, or globally in some dot-file in my home directory?

I ask because my git repository is public-readable on my home directory (we have a homes-are-readable policy in our laboratory), and I am afraid that this might leak my ssh credentials to all the lab.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [Does Git-Svn Store Svn Passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605519/does-git-svn-store-svn-passwords), they are stored in `~/.subversion`, so as long as your home directory itself is not public readable you shouldn't have a problem (though as I've just read your last line a bit more thoroughly, you may have a problem).

Comment: +1 for the purely password-based link (I had the key-based approach in mind)

Comment: Even if $HOME is publicly readable, readability of `~/.subversion` can be limited to the owner.

Comment: Hopefully, yes. If the lab doesn't have something ensuring that the whole of your home directory is public, then Federico could remove word readability on that directory.

Comment: The permissions of ~/.subversion/auth are already drwx------: apparently subversion sets the default permissions right even in this scenario. So problem solved, there is a sensible default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your SSH server to use key-based authentication? It's likely that your private key (password protected or not) is in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `~/.ssh/id_dsa` (the public key being the `.pub` file associated with them). You should definitely protect those directories, although, in most cases, `ssh` won't even let it work if they're readable by someone else (other than root).

Comment: as a side note to your comment that "ssh won't let it work" - I've fallen foul of that problem - it took me a fair while before I tried ssh -vvv to see that ssh was protecting me from dangerous permissions in my home directory - I think it was the fact that $HOME was actually group writable - which in turn makes $HOME/.ssh vulnerable.