# How to do svn commit as different user?

Tags: svn

I did checkout of my codebase via

`'svn co svn+ssh://radek@repository.server.com/var/lib/svne2/edumate2/trunk/ trunk/'`

I wrote little web application to do merge and check in into the code base that works nicely. Now I want to make this application available for developers. Right now all commits are made under my name.

**How can I do commit under different svn user?**

I tried `svn --username kon ci -m 'EDU-8319 into trunk' /srv/www/htdocs/merging/trunk` and the commit went successfully but under my name. svn didn't display any error nor asked for kon's password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `svn+ssh`, so `svn` will ignore the `--username` parameter (since the SVN server will just use your login username).

Try `svn relocate svn+ssh://<new-user>@repository.server.com/var/lib/svne2/edumate2/trunk/`, then committing.

Comment: What would the relocate do? Is that time consuming? The repository contains like 15000 files.

Comment: Relocate basically changes the repository URL. It is almost entirely a local operation; the repository is only contacted to ensure it has the same UUID and path. It should be relatively quick (few minutes at worst).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a config file to your ~/.ssh directory so svn+ssh always uses this user:

```
Host svn.server.hostname
  User svn.username
```

For more info check:
http://www.highlevelbits.com/2007/04/svn-over-ssh-prompts-for-wrong-username.html

If found this solution via tjstankus @ [Subversion ignoring "--password" and "--username" options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687/subversion-ignoring-password-and-username-options)