# Change SVN repository URL

Tags: svn, svn-repository

My current SVN structure:

```
Path: .
URL: svn://someaddress.com.tr/project
Repository Root: svn://someaddress.com.tr
Repository UUID: -------------------------------------
Revision: 10297
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: ----
Last Changed Rev: 9812
Last Changed Date: 2010-12-20 17:38:48 +0100 (Mon, 20 Dec 2010)
```

But our project (hence the SVN service) will work over `sub.someaddress.com.tr` instead of `someaddress.com.tr` (someaddress.com.tr will be redirected to somewhere else soon).

Since it is the development server, I could not be sure about what to do. Will I need to use `svn switch` or `svn switch --relocate`? Also, will I need to switch svn root **someaddress.com.tr** or the project branch **someaddress.com.tr/project**?

Comment: for anyone need changing `svn url`, see: [SVN-relocate-error-invalid-relocation-destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117615/svn-relocate-error-invalid-relocation-destination)

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Given that the Apache Subversion server will be moved to this new DNS alias: `sub.someaddress.com.tr`:

- With Subversion 1.7 or higher, use [`svn relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html). Relocate is used when the SVN server's location changes. `switch` is only used if you want to change your local working copy to another branch or another path.  If using TortoiseSVN, you may follow instructions from the [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html). If using the SVN command line interface, refer to [this section of SVN's documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html). The command should look like this:

  `svn relocate svn://sub.someaddress.com.tr/project`
- Keep using `/project` given that the actual contents of your repository probably won't change.

Note: `svn relocate` is not available before version 1.7 (thanks to ColinM for the info). In older versions you would use:

```
    svn switch --relocate OLD NEW
```

Comment: The additional TortoiseSVN links are very helpful, thanks for that

Comment: Didn't know about the `switch` command all the documentation I found online is for newer versions.

Comment: This comes handy when I need to relocate from +ssh URL to non-SSH or vice versa, for example: svn switch --relocate svn+ssh://_svn_server_/_svn_project_/_svn_branch_ svn://_svn_server_/_svn_project_/_svn_branch_. The last is especially helpful if you do automated checkout as svn+ssh on several nodes using Jenkins API and some of them (Windows nodes) don't have SSH, but you need to login to the build machine and "svn update" manually to test some quick fix.

Answer (score 17):

Grepping the URL before and after might give you some peace of mind:

```
svn info | grep URL

  URL: svn://svnrepo.rz.mycompany.org/repos/trunk/DataPortal
  Relative URL: (...doesn't matter...)
```

And checking on your version (to be >1.7) to ensure, `svn relocate` is the right thing to use:

```
svn --version
```

**Lastly, adding to the above, if your repository url change also involves a change of protocol you might need to state the before *and* after url** (also [see here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html))

```
svn relocate svn://svnrepo.rz.mycompany.org/repos/trunk/DataPortal
    https://svngate.mycompany.org/svn/repos/trunk/DataPortal
```

All in one single line of course.Thereafter, get the good feeling, that all went smoothly:

```
svn info | grep URL:
```

If you feel like it, a bit more of self-assurance, the new svn repo URL is connected and working:

```
svn status --show-updates
svn diff
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using TortoiseSVN client then you can follow the below steps

Right-click in the source directory and then click on **SVN Relocate** [image: Image#1]

After that, you need to change the URL to what you want, click ok, it will be taking a few seconds.[image: Image#2]

Comment: To see this menu on right click of a folder, first you may need to enable the setting via: right click on folder > svn settings > context menu > select Relocate option.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the `svn relocate` command (as well as `svn switch --relocate`) failed for some reason (maybe the repo was not moved correctly, or something else). I faced this error:

```
$ svn relocate NEW_SERVER
svn: E195009: The repository at 'NEW_SERVER' has uuid 'e7500204-160a-403c-b4b6-6bc4f25883ea', but the WC has '3a8c444c-5998-40fb-8cb3-409b74712e46'
```

I did not want to redownload the whole repository, so I found a workaround. It worked in my case, but generally I can imagine a lot of things can get broken (so either backup your working copy, or be ready to re-checkout the whole repo if something goes wrong).

The repo address and its UUID are saved in the `.svn/wc.db` SQLite database file in your working copy. Just open the database (e.g. in SQLite Browser), browse table REPOSITORY, and change the `root` and `uuid` column values to the new ones. You can find the UUID of the new repo by issuing `svn info NEW_SERVER`.

Again, treat this as a last resort method.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Could you be more specific?

Comment: If you read my post carefully, I do not suggest to run any commands. I suggest editing the SQLite DB.

Comment: But editing the SQLite DB involves running commands. SQL commands.

Comment: Turns out you can't use sqlite; you have to use sqlitebrowser as suggested. Weird.

Comment: I did it with sqlite3 and it worked pretty well in my case. On terminal:
sqlite3 wc.db
then:
sqlite> update REPOSITORY set root='svn+ssh://192.168.0.20/var/svn-repos/myrepo' where id=1;

check your value with
 select * from REPOSITORY;

Answer (score 2):

This was a little painful for me to get the full command line instruction.  The suggestion by @Mahi works, but my goal was to automate this through commandline. The following is what worked for me:

```
svn relocate https://10.29.52.20/svn/src https://10.32.128.41/svn/src --non-interactive --username=myuser --password=mypass --trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca,cn-mismatch,expired,not-yet-valid,other w:/src
```

- The first web address is the "FROM" or old address
- The second web address is the "TO" or new address.
- Substitute your svn username and password in place of `myuser` and `mypass`.
- The other tricky part was making sure to include the source code path ... which in my case was `w:/src`.

Answer (score 1):

If U want commit to a new empty Repo ,You can checkout the new empty Repo  and commit to new remote repo.
**chekout a new empty Repo won't delete your local files.**
**try this:**
for example,
remote repo url : https://example.com/SVNTest

`cd [YOUR PROJECT PATH]
rm -rf .svn
svn co https://example.com/SVNTest ../[YOUR PROJECT DIR NAME]
svn add ./*
svn ci -m"changed repo url"`

Comment: What will this do to the history?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, disconnect the project (Team > Disconnect) and delete the metadata, then connect the project to the new repository.
over the project, right click, team, disconnect
[image]

Comment: what is the metadata path? How to connect to new repo?