# How to make svn aware of a new servername for the repository?

Tags: svn

I have my svn repository locally in `path/to/repo/trunk`. In my `/etc/hosts`, the name  "reposerver" is linked to the (static) IP-Address of my machine.

Until now, svn used `svn+ssh://jody@reposerver/path/to/repo/trunk` to connect to the repository. But now the university has changed its network policy and i can no longer use fixed IP addresses, but must use the reposerver's "full name", `reposerver.aim.uzh.ch`.

So now svn should use `svn+ssh://jody@reposerver.aim.uzh.ch/path/to/repo/trunk` to connect to the repository.

Is there an easy way to make this change, or do i have to set up a new repository?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change SVN repository URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944222/change-svn-repository-url)

Comment: FYI, the local files in Subversion are called "working copy" while the data stored on the server are called "repository". You seem to use "repository" for both entities but, in centralized VCS, there's a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

The `svn relocate` subcommand is made exactly for this purpose. Or, to quote from `svn help relocate`:

> Relocate the working copy to point to a different repository root URL.

In your example, it would be:

```
svn relocate svn+ssh://jody@reposerver.aim.uzh.ch/path/to/repo /your/local/working_copy
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

```
svn relocate svn+ssh://reposerver.aim.uzh.ch/path/to/repo/trunk
```

This makes the required changes and svn can be used as before.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer. The 48 hour grace period should have expired by now.