# Making latest subversion exec point to my restored subversion data directory

Tags: svn

I need to point my new subversion exec to my existing svn repository.

I had to reinstall my OS to latest Fedora 39.
I have been using subversion for many years and it has been working well for my deltas.

Now my latest OS comes with svn 1.14.3 but needs to point to my restored directory shown below.
I am not sure my last svndump is reliable.
I therefore would like to use the backup directory of the actual repository directory if possible.

OS: Fedora 39
svn: svn, version 1.14.3 (r1914484)

Given my subversion directory shown below, my question is:
How do I get svn to "point" to this restored directory again?
Would I just be able to svnadmin load this directory? or is something else suggested?

```
$ ls -l /home/svn-repo
total 8

-rw-------. 1 dev1 dev 229 Mar  8 12:53 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 1 dev1 dev  38 Mar  8 12:53 locks
drwxr-xr-x. 1 dev1 dev 306 Mar  8 12:53 hooks
drwxr-xr-x. 1 dev1 dev  48 Mar  8 12:53 conf
-r--r--r--. 1 dev1 dev   2 Mar  8 12:53 format
drwxr-xr-x. 1 dev1 dev 320 Mar  8 12:53 db
```

Eg, If I issue command "svn log ." for instance in a svn controlled directory,
the error I get is 'Unable to connect to repository at URL 'file:///home/svn-repo/e-svn/...'

If this were a new install, i'd do a svnadmin create file://home/svn-repo/e-svn.
I'd then get an empty subversion repository and I'd start commiting my versions.
Done.

Now I'd like to say something like
svnadmin "look and reconnect to my existing repo directory" ?

I guess I could create a brand new repo, and then just copy the contents
of the old repository directory into the new directory location and
see what comes of it? But I figured there was a tried/true way to doing this.

Comment: It sound as if you would only need to `svn relocate file:///home/svn-repo` as explained in [Change SVN repository URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944222/change-svn-repository-url)